# How would I line the snow board products up with the names and prices?

Tags: css, html, center

I am doing a project for school and cannot figure out how to line the snowboard pictures up with the names of the products and prices. I need them to line up so it would look like a product page from a websiteHow would I line this all up?

```
<!--Doctype tells the browser the rules to follow-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--First required tag-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<!--The head is just information-->
<!--The title is what is shown on the tab bar on the browser--> 
<title>Snowboards</title>
<!--Meta is data about the data. This is the english character set-->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ski store.css"/>
</head>
<!--The body is what is shown on the browser-->
<body>

<div id="products">
<div>
<img src="burton1.jpeg" style="float: left;"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="burton2.jpeg" style="float: left;"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="soloman1.jpg" style="float: left; height: 300px;"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="soloman2.jpg" style="float: left; height: 300px;"/>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<h3 >Burton Custom Flying V</br>$550</h3>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<h3 >Burton Sherlock</br>$500</h3>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<h3 >Salomon Pulse</br>$270</h3>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<h3 > Salomon Protocol</br>$700</h3>
</div>





<!--Always the last two tags-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @codehorse there is now css for this code. This is all there is right now.

Comment: @codehorse its there for the menu, which I didn't include because it wasn't needed for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way you could make them line up is by doing this

```
h3 {
    line-height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    }

#products > div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Adjust the pixels according to how you want it.

Put that in your CSS of course. Or else you got to style each div and h3, which would be a lot more work.

Comment: This affects the container div as well, try `#products>div`
But I would suggest adding a css class to all the divs which contain product images

Comment: No worries :)
@KStahljr get rid of the inline css as well, it will override the styles you put in the css file.

Comment: That just made it go vertical now.

Comment: @codehorse yes... I just went and took out the second line of the css for the #products and it worked... I just had to adjust the pixels. Thanks a ton! Now I just have to do this with two more lines on this page and then on 3 more pages with different pictures. joy.

Comment: @codehorse this is gonna sound silly. But when I went to go out the second line of boards it actually messed it up and it wouldn't go back.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly, highly recommend a table for this. The code might be:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src=snowboard1.jpg width=100%></td>
<td><img src=snowboard2.jpg width=100%></td>
<td><img src=snowboard3.jpg width=100%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h1 align=center>The Snowboard 1</h1><br><h1 align=center>$100</h1></td>
<td><h1 align=center>The Snowboard 2</h1><br><h1 align=center>$200</h1></td>
<td><h1 align=center>The Snowboard 3</h1><br><h1 align=center>$300</h1></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Obviously, just use the actual names and prices of the snowboards, and you can add more `<td>`'s as is needed.

Comment: This worked except for the fact that now one of the boards is a lot smaller than it needs to be.

Comment: Add `width=100%` to the img tags. That or get a bigger picture of the snowboard.

Comment: I would highly, highly recommend learning CSS, to both the author of the original post and the author of this answer.

Comment: I know CSS, but in this case a table works far better than CSS does, simply because of how they're being arranged.

Comment: @KonstantinLevin I am also new at this. This is a final project for school that I am working on. I do know CSS but just not as well as everyone else.